# QList<T> runtime error

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qlist

I have a QList for store some item on QgraphicsScene like:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> lineList;
```

when I want to use it like:

```
lineList[itemIndex++]=scene->createItemGroup(groupItems);
```

i got a runtime error.
I'm curios why?

*by the way I know about linelist.append()*

thanks.

Comment: Do you also get the runtime error when you use append?

Comment: no, I know about append. I need surf around QList with my index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create a new QList, you should use `QList::append() or << operator`. From Qt Docs:

> T & QList::operator[](int i)
>   Returns the item at index position i as a modifiable reference. i must be a valid index position in the list (i.e., 0 <= i < size()).
>   This function is very fast (constant time).
>   See also at() and value().

So `QList::operator[]` can't be used to populate list like that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `itemIndex++` is equals or below to `lineList.size()`, you can use [QList::insert](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#insert)

```
lineList.insert(itemIndex++, scene->createItemGroup(groupItems));
```

Anyway, it is preferable to use `append` for extending your list by one unit.